# How to tell if app user is upgrading or new purchaser?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I would like to switch my app from paid to free with in app purchase, but I don't want to make my current users pay twice. Is there a way to know if a user is upgrading or new?

Comment: This is now possible under iOS 7 with proper receipt verification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't tell if a user is a new user or a previous owner of the app.  Let's say a previous owner of the app buys a new device and installs the latest (IAP) version; there's nothing to let you know that user is new or existing.

If you want to maintain two separate App IDs you could release two versions of your app: one that does not have IAP but costs money (for your existing customers) and one that's free and has the IAP.

Answer (score 1):

*updated*
If your IAP product's type is **non-consumable**, user can not buy it again.

Comment: Not quite. Consumable IAPs can be bought many times--non-consumable are the type that cannot be bought again, and Apple guidelines require that you allow a user to restore them. However, all of this is irrelevant to the question at hand.

Answer (score 0):

what you could do is an upgrade of your paid version that allows a user to generate a special code that they could use (once! some server connection would be useful to register these codes) in the new "free" app to get an upgrade to the full version.